# Prove uniqueness theoremn via Gronwall inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-inequality, initial-value-problems

A question says:

> Prove Theorem 1.7 (Uniqueness). Hint: suppose that $x$ and $x^*$ are distinct solutions to the same IVP (from the same initial point). Consider the function $\nu(t)=||x(t)-x^*(t)||_1$ to he integral representation of the solutions $x$ and $x^*$ and apply the Gronwall inequality.

The gronwall inequality is given in my notes:

> $u(t) <= a + b \int_0^t u(s) ds$
>
> then we have
>
> $u(t) <= ae^{bt}$

My attempt:

Consider the ode:
$\dot{x} = f(t, x)$

Consider: 
$\nu(t)=||x(t)-x^*(t)||$

$x(t) - x^*(t) <= a + b\int_0^t[x(s)-x^*(s)]ds$

$\implies x(t) - x^*(t) <= ae^{bt}$

but 
$x(t) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t f(s,x(s)) ds$

and 
$x^*(t) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t f(s,x^*(s)) ds$

$x(t) - x^*(t) = \int_{t_0}^t [f(s,x(s))-f(s,x^*(s))] ds$

$||x(t) - x^*(t)|| = ||\int_{t_0}^t [f(s,x(s))-f(s,x^*(s))] ds||$

But:
$||\int_{t_0}^t [f(s,x(s))-f(s,x^*(s))] ds||<= \int_{t_0}^t ||f(s,x(s))-f(s,x^*(s))|| ds$

I don't know how I can change from $f$ to $x(t)$ now... Maybe I've gone off on a wrong tangent?

Comment: What are your assumptions on $f$?

Comment: @Jonas just edited to add $\dot{x}=f$ in the post.

Comment: @Jonas Not in the question. But in the given Uniqueness Theorem in my notes, it does say $f$ is locally Lipschitz continous in $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, an important correction. It should be:

> If $u(t) \le a + b \int_{t_0}^t u(s) \,ds$ **for all** $t\in[t_0,T]$, then $u(t) \le ae^{bt}$ **for all** $t\in[t_0,T]$.

What you wrote is not true in general.

On any compact set you can write $$\int_{t_0}^t \|f(s,x(s))-f(s,x^*(s))\| \,ds\le L\int_{t_0}^t \|x(s)-x^*(s)\| \,ds$$ for some constant $L$. More precisely, in some neighborhood of $t_0$ your solutions $x$ and $x^*$ are controlled by Gronwall's lemma and so they will have a uniform bound; this is what allows you to consider a compact set.

After this technical issue you can apply once more Gronwall's lemma after noting that
$$
\nu(t)\le L\int_{t_0}^t \nu(s) \,ds
$$
in that neighborhood of $t_0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "compact set"?
Also, is it necessary for the norm to be 1-norm? (Can we use the 2-norm, or 3-norm, etc. instead?)

Comment: You can use whatever norm you want. What is then your definition of locally Lipschitz?

Comment: Local Lipchitz continous:
A continous function $$f:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n -> \mathbb{R}^n$$ satisfies a local Lipschitz condition in $x$ if for each $\alpha,\beta > 0$, there exists $M>0$ such that,
$$||f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)||_1 \leq M||x_1 - x_2 ||_1$$
for all $t\in R$ and $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $|t| \leq \beta$ and $|x_1|,|x_2| \leq \alpha $

Comment: Great, so notice that the set of all $(t,x)$ satisfying $|t|\le\beta$ and $\|x\|\le\alpha$ is a compact set (which here means that it is closed and bounded). You can consider this set in my answer.